# Jenkins: How to concat variable and strings in a single line

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I have a Jenkinsfile in which I need to prepare a zip file path by concatenating the variables and strings. I tried the snippet below, but its breaking up to multiple line like this:

```
13:14:02  Zip File Path: /apps/external/5/jenkins-node-home/workspace/APPL004316/APIN004621
13:14:02  /my_project
13:14:02  -0.1.29
13:14:02  -SNAPSHOT.zip
```

Expecting output to be: `/apps/external/5/jenkins-node-home/workspace/APPL004316/APIN004621/my_project-0.1.29-SNAPSHOT.zip`
Snippet:

```
stage('Zip') {
            steps {
                script {
                    env.VERSION = sh script: 'grep -m 1 version_number ${WORKSPACE}/ComponentInfo.toml | tr -s \' \' | tr -d \'"\' | tr -d "\'" | cut -d\' \' -f3', returnStdout: true
                    echo "Version: ${env.VERSION}"
                    env.PROJECT = sh script: 'echo "${WORKSPACE}"|rev|cut -d\'/\' -f1|cut -d\'@\' -f2|rev', returnStdout: true
                    echo "Project: ${env.PROJECT}"
                    env.BASEPATH = sh script: 'echo ${WORKSPACE%/*}' , returnStdout: true
                    env.ZIP_FILEPATH = "${env.BASEPATH}/${env.PROJECT}-${env.VERSION}-SNAPSHOT.zip"
                    echo "Zip File Path: ${env.ZIP_FILEPATH}"
                }
            }
        }
```

I have tried using **"+"** also, but getting the same result:

```
env.ZIP_FILEPATH = env.BASEPATH+"/"+env.PROJECT+"-"+env.VERSION+"-SNAPSHOT.zip"
```

Comment: Just trim the new lines from your returned output: `env.ZIP_FILEPATH = "${env.BASEPATH.trim()}/${env.PROJECT.trim()}-${env.VERSION.trim()}-SNAPSHOT.zip"`

Comment: Thanks @NoamHelmer it worked.  Posting your comment as an answer and closing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @NoamHelmer said, adding a `.trim()` worked.

`env.ZIP_FILEPATH = "${env.BASEPATH.trim()}/${env.PROJECT.trim()}-${env.VERSION.trim()}-SNAPSHOT.zip"`

Thanks Noam